# Error in my simple struts application

Tags: struts, struts-1

Error:  inconvertible types

my loginAction file's code:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
{
    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;

    if (loginForm.getUserName().equals(loginForm.getPassword())) 
    {
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);
    }
}
```

my struts-config file's code:

```
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/login.jsp" name="LoginForm" path="/Login" scope="session"                type="com.strutsmyaction.LoginAction">
         <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" />
         <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

my loginform file's code

> public class LoginForm
>   {  String userName;    String password;
>      public String getUserName()     {
>      System.out.println("Inside getter "+userName);
>      return userName;
>      }
>      public void setUserName(String userName) {
>       System.out.println("Inside setter "+userName);
>       this.userName = userName;
>      }
>      public String getPassword() {
>       return password;
>     }
>   public void setPassword(String password) {
>    this.password = password;
>   }
>   }

Comment: What are SUCCESS and FAILURE (Capitals) in your code ?

Comment: Are you using Struts or Struts2? Your code is from Struts but in your question you are asking for Struts2 ...

Comment: Why people is upvoting this? If he doesn't explain which is the framework he is using, how this could be a good question?

Comment: I think the issue is related to data conversion. Please post the LoginForm class and the html form element.

Comment: Check again code, i will add my login form file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think This will work ..

```
if (loginForm.getUserName().equals(loginForm.getPassword())) 
{
    return mapping.findForward("success");
} 
else 
{
    return mapping.findForward("failure");
}
```